# What can Google Trends do that Google Insights cannot?

Tags: google-trends

Google has two applications that gives us access to all "Search History".

One is [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/) and the other is [Google Insights](http://www.google.com/insights/search/).

Does anyone know what can Google Trends do that Google Insights cannot? Basically, what do we need Google Trends for?

Answer (score 1):

> **How is Google Insights for Search different from Google Trends?**
>
> While Google Insights for Search and Google Trends use the same data, Insights for Search is geared towards users (such as researchers or advertisers) who may find some of its advanced features more useful for their purposes.

[Source](http://support.google.com/insights/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=117683).

Comment: Check [this Search Engine Land article](http://searchengineland.com/google-insights-for-search-launches-14526) also.

Comment: Yes, but what is the point of Google Trends? Anyone who wants to use Trends can simply use Insights, right?